# p:editor shows "true" on initial page load

Tags: jsf, primefaces, rich-text-editor

I've inserted an editor component to a simple form and when web page is loaded instead of pre-defined text(question marks) I see the word `true` in the editor.

I've tried to cut html special characters from the template, looked into another SO answers (most of them was about `<p:ajax>` instead of `<f:ajax>` and putting editor in the dialog, which is not the case here). I'm using PrimeFaces 5.2.

My controller:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "mailTemplateBean")
public class MailTemplateBean extends BaseWebBean {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        text = "?????????????";
    }

    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

My view:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:editor id="editor" widgetVar="editorWidget"
        value="#{mailTemplateBean.text}" width="600" />
    <p:commandButton value="Update" update="editor"
        icon="ui-icon-disk" />

</h:form>
```

Update: Behavior is different in Chrome and Firefox. Chrome - starts with editor disabled and empty. Only when I click on command button - it's refreshed and the right text is shown. What's described above - it's how it works (or not) in Firefox.

Comment: autoupdate should be autoUpdate and can only be "true" or "false", but I don't know if it has anything to do with anything

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar thanks for this, but it haven't fixed the issue.

Comment: Does it fail when initially loading the page or when pressing the commandButton? And does it work when removing the `p:messages`? If not, please remove it from the code to make it [mcve]

Comment: @Kukeltje removed messages - same. When pressing button, the text is updated from "true" to whatever I set in the backing bean. Looks like I'm going to try some onload magic.

Comment: @Kukeltje you gave me an idea how to fix it, thanks!

Comment: I copy pasted your code  as it is above (with implementing an empty BaseWebBean) and it just works on FireFox, IE and Chrome on WildFly 8.0.1. So there must be something else wrong on your side. Did you check the browser console for errors? Are you sure this page is loaded correctly? From a 'get' request or is it something that is loaded as a response on a post?

Comment: works for wildfly 8.2 to

Comment: No errors in console, both on chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is how it's intended to work, but I fixed the issue putting the following line into the form:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="editor" autoRun="true"/>
```

It refreshes the editor after the page is loaded and value from backing bean is displayed properly.

Comment: This is not a fix, it is a workaround for a non identified other cause... I will investigate a little...

Comment: As mentioned above, it just works, so this workaround is not the real solution to the problem, just masquarading that something else fails

Comment: The reason I didn't accepted the answer. @Kukeltje, I tried pf5.3, the app is running on WebSphere 8.5. any other information that can help?

Comment: Yes, an [mcve] as stated above as there must be more in the view